# How can I add a button for AAD login in existing policy w/ self asserted template?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created a custom policy for logging in. However, it only contemplates the usual user/password login. I now want to add a Microsoft login button.

My question is, how would I change the HTML template to do it? I am currently working with the [selfasserted.cshtml one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Azure-AD-B2C-page-templates/blob/master/slate_gray/selfAsserted.html), and as I understand these are predefined, so changing it is either very difficult or impossible.

I've set up Microsoft authentication in another page that has a different policy, and XML-wise I'm more or less confident on what to do, but I fail to see how to make said change on the interface.

[image]

Comment: Usually you would add the identity provider as an option for the login. But you need to use a "CombinedSignInSignup" orchestration step. Then the button is injected by B2C into your HTML, just like the other form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the identity provider as a `ClaimsExchange` to the `CombinedSignInAndSignUp` orchestration steps of your XML policy to surface it to the UI.

You can learn how to add an identity provider in the [Microsoft Learn - Add MSA identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) documentation.

Once it is visible to the UI, you can apply your custom styling.